# Is there any pre-defined flag from detox that I can know App is running on detox?

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm looking for some pre-defined flag (macro) so I can skip a specific code in my App when I run detox.

```
if (__RUNNING_ON_DETOX__) {
  return; // skip this function
}
```

As a workaround, I'm using `react-native-config` and put `ENVFILE` on detox build.
But I'm looking for a simpler way.
If there is no flag that is provided from detox, I like to know the way that I could inject an inline `export` at least.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No predefined flag, but you can mock out the dependency that you don't want to interact with instead:

- [old detox guide focused on RN <59](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/01ad250fe4168502a57339b8bcab0ec5a5c89e4b/docs/Guide.Mocking.md)
- [updated detox guide (as of Oct 2023)](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/c8f7421256d23fefc1b802f2501bd2bcfd83db01/docs/guide/mocking.md)

Comment: Oh, great. Thanks a lot. 

Comment: That link is dead

Comment: That is_really helpful, @brian